# Different worker types same queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Is it ok with Sidekiq, to have two different workers consuming the same queue, even though the jobs might be different (different arguments for example)?

So, if I have this:

```
class WorkerType1
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :charging
end

class WorkerType2
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :charging
end
```

And we do stuff like:

```
WorkerType1.perform_async(argument1, argument2)

WorkerType2.perform_async(another_type_of_argument)
```

Is that ok? Or it will cause troubles because we have two different classes consuming the same queue with different job types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.  Sidekiq knows which arguments go with which worker type.

Comment: So, when a job is enqueued, it's also enqueued the class that should consume it, yes? Thanks Mike.